# ServerSide application consumes 100% of CPU

Tags: java, loops, server, client, infinite

So the title almost says it all, I have a client-server program I wrote, the issue is that even when there is NO client's connected, the server consumes INSANE amounts of CPU power, and I think it's related to the infinite while loop you use to constantly accept clients.

```
while (true) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {}

    try {
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O error: " + e);
    }

    new CThread(socket).start();
    if(r == null) break;
}
```

This always seems to overload the CPU, I do know it's an infinite loop, but it just hogs resources. Is there any way to stop this?

I have tried removing it and noticed much better performance. but was only able to accept 1 client.

If it is relevant, which I doubt it is, my system specs...
Intel Xeon E5520 @ 2.27 GHz
24 GB DDR3 1333 MHz
and 1 mbps Ethernet

Is there any simple alternatives to this loop of death? Or am I doing something wrong? Below is my CThread Class which I use to run the whole thing.

**EDIT: this is after I found the solution, to everyone else that tries to do this, make sure you include a "return;" in your try catch inside the loop. Because, when the client disconnects and the server sends it's packets and whatnot, it throws an Exception which will then call the Catch and run the "return;" which will terminate the thread.**

```
class CThread extends Thread {
    protected Socket s;
    public ObjectOutputStream out;
    public ObjectInputStream in;
    public Player p = null;
    public static worldTile wt = null;  
    public CThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.s = clientSocket;
        System.out.println("New Client :D");
    }
    public synchronized void run() {

        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            out.flush();
            out.writeObject("Welcome client :)");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return;
        }

        while (true) {
            try {
            String d = (String) in.readObject();
               if(d.startsWith("Login:[")) {//Login:[user,pass]
                   String[] args = d.substring("Login:[".length(), d.indexOf("]")).split(",");
                   int log = login(args);
                   if(log != -1)
                       p = new Player(log);
                   out.writeObject(log);
               }
               else if(d.startsWith("Register:[")) {//Register:[user,pass]
                   String[] args = d.substring("Register:[".length(), d.indexOf("]")).split(",");
                   int reg = register(args);
                   if(reg != -1)
                       p = new Player(reg);
                   out.writeObject(reg);
               }
               else if(d.startsWith("Tile:[")) {//Tile:[w,x,y]
                   Tile t = (Tile) in.readObject();
                   String[] args = d.substring("Tile:[".length(),d.indexOf(']')).split(",");
                   int[] a = new int[3];
                   for(int x = 0; x < args.length; x++) {
                       a[x] = Integer.parseInt(args[x]);
                   }
                   if(wt.worldid==a[0]) {
                       wt.info[a[1]][a[2]] = t;
                   }
                   else {
                       wt.write();
                       wt = new worldTile("world"+a[0]);
                       wt.info[a[1]][a[2]] = t;
                   }
               }
               else if(d.startsWith("Position:")) { // Position:[w]
                   int world = Integer.parseInt(d.substring("Position:".length()));
                   out.writeObject(new BufferTile("world"+world));
               }
               else if(d.startsWith("Gib Bank")) {
                   out.writeObject(p.n.bank);
               }
               else if(d.startsWith("Gib Layout")) {
                   out.writeObject(PlayerManager.worlds);
               }

            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    wt.write();
                    p.logout();
                } catch(Exception e2) {}
                //System.out.println("Connection Error!");
            }
            catch(IOException e) {}
            catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly because you are creating multiple CThread objects and starting each one?

Comment: So what's an alternative? I've looked around and most Server-Client applications just have something really similar, or use Java NIO but I'd prefer not to use that.

Comment: Check to see if the server actually accepts the socket. If the server doesn’t open a return socket, DON’T create a new CThread object and start it. Only create and start a new CThread object when a connection is secured.

Comment: So in the same try catch as the serversocket initialization, I move the CThread object with it?

Comment: That would be a good start. Try that and let me know how that goes.

Comment: `while (true) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                if(socket.isConnected())
                 new CThread(socket).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("I/O error: " + e);
            }
            if(r == null) break;
        }`
so something like this right? Sorry, there's no formatting for comments :P

Comment: Yeah, that looks awesome. Try it out!

Comment: Ok, I will wait a few minuets and get back to you :)

Comment: Alright, good luck!

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it did once again reach 100%, although I followed it more carefully and it seemed to jump up every time I closed the client and started it back up again. I'm not sure but maybe it's not "disposing" of the thread? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Well how long are these threads supposed to be running?

Comment: This is extremely unclear.  The loop with `sleep(500)` is completely unnecessary as `ServerSocket#accept()` blocks until a connection arrives.  Are you seeing lots of `I/O error: ...` messages? You should instantiate `CThread` inside the `try` right after the `accept()`.  Have you done any profiling? Can you identify where the time is being spent?  It could be anywhere in `CThread`.

Comment: The sleep(500) was a last ditch attempt, there are no messages I am aware of, and I have tried inside the try (talked about it already with Jacob), what is profiling? and what do you mean by "where the time is being spent"

Comment: `catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)` is horrible code smell. This should never happen in working code and if you feel a need to catch it then you have other problems.  Also `catch(IOException e) {}` -- what happens if there IS an `IOException`?  Finally, I fixed the indentation on the first block. I strongly suggest you fix it in the second block so you can more easily spot unexpected nesting problems.

Comment: The arrayindex thing was soley for testing, and I changed all the IO exceptions to "return;" to exit the thread, but is an IOException thrown when the client disconnects?

Comment: Do you see a flurry of `New Client :D` messages? If not, then it's not the socket accept loop where the problem lies, it's an infinite loop in the `CThread` code, or maybe even somewhere else you haven't shown us.  Until you can actually _demonstrate_ that the problem lies in the code you posted, it's going to be nearly impossible for anyone to help you unless some kind soul decides to invest a half hour studying what you have posted and gets lucky.

Comment: I think I fixed it, thanks :)
I just replaced all the IOExceptions with return; and it works.

Comment: _"I think I fixed it, thanks :) I just replaced all the IOExceptions with return; and it works"_ -- um, that's the equivalent of "I put black tape over the check-engine light and now it works".

Comment: how so? it makes sense why it would